# Regex anything before, with groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

In JS, What I should do to match and put anything before `>` or `~` into group `one` in this regex pattern.

Pattern: `(?<one>.*)(?:>|~)(?<two>.*)` https://regex101.com/r/AOY4k0/1/

Strings:

```
aaa
bbb>ccc
ddd~eee
```

In this example, `aaa` should go into the `<one>` group.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
^(?<one>.*?)(?:(?:>|~)(?<two>.*))?$
```

**Alternative**:

```js
^(?<one>.*?)(?:[>~](?<two>.*))?$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/AOY4k0/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<one>                    group and capture to "one":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "one"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ~                        '~'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<two>                  group and capture to "two":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of "two"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a character class and a  [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^`

```
^(?<one>[^>~\n]+)(?:[>~](?<two>.*))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<one>[^>~\n]+)` Group **one** match 1+ times any char other than `>` `~` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[>~]` Match either `>` or `~`
  - `(?<two>.*)` Group **two** match 0+ times any character except a newline
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n1M2lQ/1)